# Why won't a new emacs window open in x11

Tags: emacs, x11

When I type `emacs &` in X11, a new window doesn't open. Instead I just get the PID of the process. This illustrates what I mean.

```
bash-3.2$ emacs &
[1] 38624
```

Why is this happening and how can I get emacs to open in a separate window?

Comment: Can we simplify the problem? If you run `emacs` as a foreground job (i.e. without the `&`), what happens? (GUI Emacs window? Terminal emacs? Nothing? Other?)

Answer (score 0):

You can't start terminal Emacs as a background job -- it needs to interact with the terminal. Whenever a background job attempts to write to the tty, it is immediately stopped.

I would expect that your next input into the terminal would have resulted in a message similar to this?

```
[1]+  Stopped                 emacs
```

(which would have been useful).

You could then foreground the job with `fg`.

Running `emacs &` only makes any sense with GUI Emacs.